# Writing tests in Appium for ActionScript-based iPad app

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, selenium, appium

I downloaded and set up `Appium` to run tests for an app developed in `ActionScript` for the `iPad`. I can run `Appium` just fine, however am having trouble actually writing tests. The problem is that I don't have any way to retrieve elements from the app. I thought I could do this with the selenium driver (I am currently creating an `IOSDriver` with `Appium`), however can't seem to figure out exactly how. All of the elements created by my application are `flash`-based ([TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) for example), so I'm not sure how to retrieve them with the normal findElement method(s).

(Note I cannot update the code to comply with my tests, it must be the tests that comply with the pre-written code)

Answer (score 0):

The Accessibility-based mechanism underlying the UI Automation feature represents every control in your app as a uniquely identifiable element. To perform an action on an element in your app, you explicitly identify that element in terms of the app’s element hierarchy.

[This link is useful Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html)

---

Tools You may like to try Although they are not exactly like UiAutomatorViewer which is for android

[Reveal App](http://revealapp.com/)

[SparkInspector](http://sparkinspector.com/)

[Ios Hierarchy-Viewer](https://github.com/glock45/iOS-Hierarchy-Viewer)

As far as Flas Elements concers Lets [Look at this tutorial.](https://seleniumonlinetrainingexpert.wordpress.com/2012/12/02/how-to-do-flash-testing-using-selenium-webdriver/)